# What is this synthetic molecular motor and what is the energy source?

Tags: thermodynamics, molecular-dynamics

In the "Molecular dynamics" entry of 2018 version of Wikipedia (it have been removed for the current version), there is such a synthetic molecular motor:

[image]

You can also find this image by searching "MD_rotor_250K_1ns" for image on Bing.

(1) Any references about this synthetic molecular motor?

(2) According to the animation, it seems to be driven by thermal energy instead of chemical energy, is that true? If so, how to explain it from the second law of thermal dynamics, since the random thermal motion seems to be transformed into more ordered directional rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [wiki article still exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_molecular_motor), with the simulation too.

[image]

> Molecular dynamics simulation of a synthetic molecular rotor composed of three molecules in a nanopore (outer diameter 6.7 nm) at 250 K

In the wiki article:

> The basic requirements for a synthetic motor are repetitive 360° motion, the consumption of energy and unidirectional rotation.

So energy has to be supplied.  There are light driven and chemically driven rotors.

The reference for the simulation is :

> Palma, C.-A.; Björk, J.; Rao, F.; Kühne, D.; Klappenberger, F.; Barth, J.V. (2014). "Topological Dynamics in Supramolecular Rotors". Nano Letters. 148: 4461–4468.

the article states that

> [As of 2020 the smallest,](https://www.pnas.org/content/early/2020/06/12/1918654117) atomically precise molecular machine has a rotor, which consist of four atom

Thermal motion is  utilized as follows in the [latest experiment](https://www.pnas.org/content/early/2020/06/12/1918654117):

> By breaking spatial inversion symmetry, the stator defines the unique sense of rotation. While thermally activated motion is nondirected, inelastic electron tunneling triggers rotations, where the degree of directionality depends on the magnitude of the STM bias voltage.

......

> This ultrasmall motor thus opens the possibility to investigate in operando effects and origins of energy dissipation during tunneling events, and, ultimately, energy harvesting at the atomic scales.